# Unable to upload wasm file on terra-station

Tags: docker, blockchain, smartcontracts, terra

I developed NFT smart contract based on Cosmwasm for Terra blockchain. It was working well, but when I upgraded `cosmwasm-std` version from `0.9.2` to `1.0.0-beta8`, despite of successful compiling and optimization of source code, storing wasm on chain is invoking error.
My code is based on https://github.com/terran6/nft_on_terra/ and deployed using following command

```sh
terrain deploy cw721-base --signer custom_tester_1 --network testnet --set-signer-as-admin
terrain sync-refs
```

This command made error as follows.

```sh
...
Optimizing cw721_base.wasm ...
Creating hashes ...
5401a4be4cccc8c52109391ed3473074941153eecb71d79bdb2fd813fe3a77d9  cw721_base.wasm
Info: sccache stats after build
Compile requests                     41
Compile requests executed            25
Cache hits                            0
Cache misses                         25
Cache misses (Rust)                  25
Cache timeouts                        0
Cache read errors                     0
Forced recaches                       0
Cache write errors                    0
Compilation failures                  0
Cache errors                          0
Non-cacheable compilations            0
Non-cacheable calls                  16
Non-compilation calls                 0
Unsupported compiler calls            0
Average cache write               0.000 s
Average cache read miss           2.733 s
Average cache read hit            0.000 s
Failed distributed compilations       0
Non-cacheable reasons:
crate-type                           12
-                                     4
Cache location                  Local disk: "/root/.cache/sccache"
Cache size                           15 MiB
Max cache size                       10 GiB
done
storing wasm bytecode on chain... !
    Error: Request failed with status code 400
    Response: failed to execute message; message index: 0: Error calling the 
    VM: Error during static Wasm validation: Wasm contract has unknown 
    interface_version_* marker export (see 
    https://github.com/CosmWasm/cosmwasm/blob/main/packages/vm/README.md): 
    store wasm contract failed: invalid request
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

This error is pressing me several days. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I downgraded to version = "0.16.0" and it works. I created an issue in cw-plus, while actually the issue is probably related to cosmwasm itself

Comment: Thank you very much! I also had to downgrade cosmwasm-std version inevitably. Terra station seems not to be compatible with the latest cosmwasm-std versions. In other words, Terra station doesn't support interface_version_8 wasm files yet. Thank you again! Best wishes!